# Appending to dynamically allocated array

Tags: c

I am trying to add data received onto a buffer which needs to be configurable at runtime (I read a size from file or command line).

So basically I determine my `buffersize` and allocate an area of memory using `calloc` (I also put a catchall to set a buffersize if it is not in the config file or command line - Let's assume we use that for now).

I am only putting applicable lines of code.

```
int buffersize=10000;
void *BuffPtr = (void *)calloc(1,buffersize * sizeof(char));
```

I then have a `recv` from UDP (I have tried receiving into char array and dynamically allocated array - both work fine)

```
// Setup socket......

void *PktBuff = (void *)calloc(1,1000 * sizeof(char));

// Loop and receive many packets......

rcvd_bytes=recv(recv_socket, PktBuff, 1000, 0);
```

I can, at this point, write the contents of `PktBuff` and it works fine. But I want to concatenate a number of received packets in my dynamically allocated array (`BuffPtr` defined above).

I have tried strcat, but I just get garbage out if I try to write the first packet received, without getting another packet.

```
strcat(BuffPtr, PktBuff);
```

What I am doing wrong??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: strcat relies on '\0' as a string terminator. Try adding it after the strcat.

Comment: You're doing the `calloc` call wrong: The first argument is the number of items to allocate (`buffersize` in the first code chunk), and the second argument is the size of each items. It should be `calloc(buffersize, sizeof(char))`.

Comment: @BigMike errr no... that assumes BuffPtr is only comprised of non \0 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Your data doesn't seem to be 0-terminated strings, you may want to use `memmove` instead.

Comment: Perhaps it could work reading in 999 bytes to PktBuff? As calloc zero inits the memory.

Comment: Or allocating 1001 bytes. That is if we assume, there are no zeros in the data.

Comment: Michael,I have tried memove it works for the first instance, then I get garbage for the second and subsequent packets.

Comment: Just be careful about what you moving where and make sure you have enough space to move things around.

Comment: OK, I have enough space, but still the same problem - My recv loop concatenates the first time, but the second time, only a single line of 'garbage' is added to the end of my dynamically allocated array - Or so it seems - The recv buffer holds the correct information, but memmove or memcpy just adds garbage.  Any Ideas Please ?

Comment: Are you adding it to the right place? Something like `memmove(buff+alreadyfilledcount,recvdbuff,bytesrecevied)` ?

Answer (score 2):

A few points and observations:

1. Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C.
2. The expression `sizeof (char)` is a wordy way of writing `1`, multiplying by it is seldom informative.
3. Make sure all your data is 0-terminated (strings), otherwise you can't use string functions since that's what they require.
4. You should probably just use an extra `size_t` counter to keep track of the number of bytes in BuffPtr, and use that and `memcpy()` to append.

Comment: Thanks, I do have a counter for the total bytes in BuffPtr, and following advice from Michael, I have used memove, which improves things marginally.  I must be missing something like a terminating string on the packet ?? Will check.

Answer (score 0):

Okay a number of issues in your code strcat is NOT the right way to append binary data. Here is a semi-robust implementation.   I have NOT checked it for syntax errors, just typed it out please study it as an example, and adjust it to your code.

```
/* total number of bytes you are willing to receive in single a single receive */ 
#define MAX_RECV_BUFFER 1000

/* total number of bytes you are willing to store in memory */
#define MAXBYTES MAX_RECV_BUFFER*1000

int append_bytes() {
    char rcvbuf[MAX_RECV_BUFFER]; /* buffer where things are received */
    void *buf = NULL; /* buffer where bytes are collected */
    size_t rcvlen; /* length of data received */
    size_t buflen = 0; /* total bytes */

    while(1) {
         void *p;
         rcvlen = recv(recv_socket, rcvbuf, MAX_RECV_BUFFER, 0);
         if ( rcvlen < 0 ) { manage_error(); }
         if ( rcvlen == 0 ) 
                 break;
         if ( buflen + rcvlen > MAXBYTES) 
                 break;
         p = realloc(buf, buflen+recvlen);
         if ( !p ) { manage_memory_error(); }
         buf = p; /* we have enough space */
         memcpy(buf+buflen, rcvbuf, recvlen); /* append new content to end of buffer */
         buflen+=recvlen; /* add length to buflen */
    }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the compiler doesn't like the memcpy. I have declared things exactly as you (removing my previous calloc) and get a compiler error referring to the buf+buflen argument in memcpy:   expression must be a pointer to a complete object type     ??????